# Is the question "What is your body figure" grammatically correct?

Tags: word-choice

Is a question "What is your body figure" grammatically  correct? 
or "What is your body sizes?" I think this one is wrong. Which one is better?

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's *grammatically* correct, but semantically odd. A more natural phrasing would be, "What is your body type?" This is, in fact, a rather common question in [bodybuilding contexts](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/becker3.htm), [women's magazines and websites](http://blissfullydomestic.com/life-bliss/beauty-and-fashion/find_your_body_type/), and [health forums](http://www.hnwellness.com/blog/uncategorized/what-is-your-body-type.html), and is the way I'd recommend asking about this topic.

"What is your body sizes?" is grammatically incorrect because *sizes* is plural but *is* is singular. "What is your body size?" would be better, and is still more natural than "What is your body figure?" Also, "What is your dress size?" is a common enough question among women (if they know each other well enough to ask about such things).

Note that *body type* and *body size* are asking for different kinds of information, and both can be highly context-specific. For example, to a bodybuilder, *body type* means [ectomorph, mesomorph, or endomorph](http://www.muscleandstrength.com/articles/body-types-ectomorph-mesomorph-endomorph.html). To a fashion-minded woman it might mean any number of things—here's a list of [twelve different types](http://www.okdani.com/2011/06/what-is-your-body-type-12-to-choose.html). *Body size* might mean dress size, height, or weight, depending on the context.

Answer (score 3):

I actually think that neither is very natural-sounding. A "body figure" could be redundant, as they might be considered synonymous. Also, "body sizes" makes it sound as if every body has multiple sizes. I would instead suggest:

> What size are you?

or

> What is your size?

When you ask someone this, they will infer the context. Are you in a shoe store? They'll give their shoe size. Are you selling them clothing? They will give you their clothing size. Note that if you are asking for a specific clothing item size, like for a pair of pants, you might want to say:

> What pants size are you?